# Line integral of vector field

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $F$ be the vector field over $\mathbb R^3$ given by $$F(x,y,z)=(4x(1+\frac{z^2}{8}),\frac{\pi}{3}\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}y),\frac{x^2z}{2}-e^{\frac{z}{3}})$$

and let $C$ be the curve parametrized by $\gamma(t)=(e^{t(t-3)},t,2t).$

Calculate $\int_c F.ds$

I've tried to calculate directly the line integral but it is a horrible integral so I guess the idea is to use some tool of multivariable calculus, the problem is I don't realize which of them is, I would appreciate suggestions to calculate this integral.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$F=\nabla\phi=\Bigl(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x},
  \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y},\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z}\Bigr)\ ,$$
where
$$\phi(x,y,z)=2x^2\Bigl(1+\frac{z^2}{8}\Bigr)+\sin\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{3}y\Bigr)
  -3e^{z/3}\ .$$
Therefore $F$ is a conservative vector field and
$$\int_C F\cdot ds=\phi(x_2,y_2,z_2)-\phi(x_1,y_1,z_1)\ ,$$
where $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ is the initial point of $C$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ is the final point.  Since you have not given in your question the initial and final values of $t$, you will need to find them and do the rest yourself.

---

. . . but I'd be prepared to make a guess at $t_1=0$, $t_2=3$, in which case $C$ goes from $(1,0,0)$ to $(1,3,6)$ and the integral is $12-3e^2$.